# 'is' or 'are' in lists of counted nouns

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions

Which of the following is correct?
Does the is/are depend on the total number of things in the list, or only on the thing immediately following the is/are?

> There is 1 apple and 1 orange available.
>   There are 1 apple and 1 orange available.

Also, would it make a difference if one would put the is/are near the end, like so?

> 1 apple and 1 orange is available.
>   1 apple and 1 orange are available.

Comment: @PeterShor I had a look at the linked question, and while the original question seems to be the same problem as I have, I struggle to understand the accepted answer. Does the is/are depend on the following component of the list, or the total amount?

Comment: I reread the linked accepted answer, and it's very difficult to understand. What I think it's saying  (for a list with the first element singular) is that formally, it should be plural. But informally, more English speakers actually use the singular than use the plural.

Comment: @PeterShor What would you chose for a mobile app then? Plural or singular?

Comment: I'd recommend going with singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is right:

> There is 1 apple and 1 orange available

This is wrong:

> There are 1 apple and 1 orange available.

I would personally say

> There is an apple and an orange available.

---

This is now wrong

> 1 apple and 1 orange is available

This is right (almost):

> 1 apple and 1 orange are available.

But again, I would say

> An apple and an orange are available.

---

These are both correct:

> There is an apple and 2 oranges available.
>   There are 2 apples and an orange available

So it depends on the number of objects the is/are is referring to first.

> 2 apples and an orange are available.
>   An apples and 2 oranges are available.

When it is at the end, it refers to the total number of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you point me to some site where I can read up on this rule?

Comment: Try http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp

Comment: I actually found that site during my research, but it doesn't say anything about subjects connected by 'and'.